# Xamarin ValueMember for UIPickerView?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, combobox, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

When working with combo boxes for windows forms application, you can have a DisplayMember (which is what is shown) and a ValueMember (which is the value that the user doesn't see but the code uses for other processes)

I was wondering if there is a similar sort of function for UIPickerViews in Xamarin

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/picker

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Comment: yeah, I did it a different way though by having different public variables in the view model and by using a list as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if there is a similar sort of function for UIPickerViews in Xamarin?

Yes! you can implement it in `UIPickerView`.

```
string[] DisplayMembers = new string[] { "January", "February", "March",...,"December" };
int[] ValueMembers = new int[] {1,2,3,...,12 };
```

And in the method of Delegate

```
public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
{
    return DisplayMembers.Length;
}

public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
    if (component == 0)
        return DisplayMembers[row];
    else
        return row.ToString();
}

public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
  //...
  var valueMember=ValueMembers[row].ToString();
  // do something you want about valueMember

}
```